# Creating my own AJAX autosuggest with full keyboard support

Tags: javascript, ajax, autosuggest

Does anyone have any experience in creating their own AJAX auto suggest text box **with full keyboard support**?

I have successfully created the auto suggest aspect by plugging in to a SQL DB and displaying results but the only way to interact with the search results is to use the mouse. I want to be able to scroll up/down with the keyboard and use the enter key to select the item and be redirected to the relevant page.

I have seen countless articles and help forum pages detailing how to scroll through HTML elements with the up/down arrows, but nothing explaining how the enter key can be incorporated into selecting the item and redirecting to the relevant page.

I am aware of all the auto suggest plugins I can use, but I have come this far creating my own and I want to be able to add extra content to the results rather than be fixed to someone else's work.

If anyone could help me out by pointing me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Cheers

Comment: Find one that is open source, fork it and make your changes.

Comment: [jqueryui.com/autocomplete/](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer *definitely* falls under the category 'point in the right direction', because I don't know if you already have code and what that looks like (if it exists).

You said you already created a dropdown with suggestions, so I'll leave out CSS and JS for styling and positioning.
Let's assume the dropdown consists of this markup:

```
<div id="suggestiondropdown">
    <span class="suggestion" data-page="[URL of page]">Suggestion 1</span>
    <span class="suggestion" data-page="[URL of page]">Suggestion 2</span>
    <span class="suggestion" data-page="[URL of page]">Suggestion 3</span>
    <span class="suggestion" data-page="[URL of page]">Suggestion 4</span>
    <span class="suggestion" data-page="[URL of page]">Suggestion 5</span>
</div>
```

With this JS you should be able to move between the suggestions with the arrow keys:

```
var suggestions = document.querySelectorAll(".suggestion"); // Now suggestions is an array with the spans
var index = 0;
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    // Style the selected as normal here:
    suggestions[index].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // UP!
        if (index <= 0) index = suggestions.length;
        index--;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 40) { // DOWN!
        if (index >= suggestions.length -1) index = -1;
        index++;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 13) { // ENTER!
         var page = suggestions[index].dataset.page;
         window.location.href = page; // Or with relative URLs, first prepend the base URL.
    }
    // Style the selected one as selected here.
    // I don't know how you want it, so I'll just give the selected one a blue background.
    suggestions[index].style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF"; // Never mind the ugly shade

}
```

**Untested**

Comment: That's great thanks, really helpful, especially the enter key URL redirection I was stumped on that. Seems to only work in Firefox though, did you know this?

Comment: It's definitely helped me yes, just want to find out why it only works in Firefox.

Comment: What does the console say? @user2026031

Comment: It is probably the `.dataset`. Try replacing that with `.getAttribute("data-page")`

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll' 
- the up/down keys aren't scrolling through the elements. Only Firefox at the moment.

Comment: Ah, I see. Wait a minute. @user2026031

Comment: Replace `.querySelectorAll(".suggestion");` with `.getElementsByClassName("suggestion");` @user2026031 Haha, it was exactly one minute according to SO! :D

Comment: No cigar with that I'm afraid - only FF recognises the getElementsByClassName it seems!

Comment: What other browsers do you test it in? And that's impossible. Are you sure you saved it right?

Comment: It really should work! http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname @user2026031

Comment: IE10 and Chrome. Definitely saved it right. Are you seeing results in all browsers then?

Comment: Perhaps there is other console output yet? `document.getElementsByClassName()` should really work in IE10 according to caniuse.com! @user2026031

Comment: Nope, I'm getting nothing in Chrome or IE. No up/down arrow interaction, bit of a shame :(

Comment: Probably there is one error in these browsers, to help you solve it I really need the console output. @user2026031

Comment: I've now turned off Compatibility mode in IE10, which has stopped the error message from appearing. The up/down arrow's still don't work and there is no error message in the console - stuck!

Comment: Hold the phone. Replaced document.onkeypress = function(e) {
 with jQuery - $(window).keydown(function (e) { and it works!

Comment: Great! @user2026031 I hope this was your last issue!

Comment: Seems to be working well, some minor issues that I can sort out. Once again thanks for your help.